# C# Receiving empty object in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get some data from the request body in a POST Controller, but the console shows empty props:

The Post Controller:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/features")]
public ActionResult<bool> AddFeatureAsync(Guid Id, [FromBody] AddRoleFeatureRequest request)
{
   Console.WriteLine(request.Name);
   Console.WriteLine(request.Description);
   Console.WriteLine(request.Id);

   return true;
}
```

The AddRoleFeatureRequest class:

```
public class AddRoleFeatureRequest
{
    public Guid Id;
    public string? Name;
    public string? Description;
}
```

The JSON data from Postman (Using body raw as Json):

```
{
    "name": "Feature ABC",
    "description": "description",
    "id": "7e12b0ad-2c82-46f0-a69e-8538efb0aa60"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your Postman curl command statement ?

Comment: You don't have any props. I only see fields: Try adding `{ get; set; }`

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have `Content-Type: application/json` header set in Postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to get some data from the request body in a POST
> Controller, but the console shows empty props:

Your reason for getting null data on your console or in controller is pretty obvious because you have defined your `AddRoleFeatureRequest` class field only which doesn't allow to set any value on it. For instance, `public string? Name;` is a field not property.  To set value, you must implement valid setter. Thus, it can be treated as [valid property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and able to assign value into it.

**Solution:**

```
public class AddRoleFeatureRequest
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** [Property without getter and setter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) will always consider as field, it will not allow you to assign value from outside.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Modifying your class defination would completely resolve your issue. No other changes required.

Answer (score 1):

Your "AddRoleFeatureRequest" class has capitals and your json data does not. This could be the source of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

the attribute names might be the reasons because they ar different then the json keys, retry it while considering letters cases,

Comment: This is unlikely to be the case, since by default the ASP.NET Core sets up the JsonSerializer to ignore the case for the inputs the controllers receive. The more likely explanation is the one that involves fully defining the properties.